# Computer RSA key changes each time I use Nox android player

Tags: android, adb

I checked "Always allow USB debugging..." for my PC in my phone. However, each time I use Nox android emulator, computer RSA key changes and I should confirm it again.

Why this happens? Is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Robert's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228350/allow-usb-debugging-for-any-pc-without-confirmation?noredirect=1#comment298311_228350), I found the answer. You have to edit permissions of `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` files in `C:\Users\%username%\.android` to prevent any modification on them.